# Why must I load a file instead of a custom surface when setting an icon?

Tags: python, pygame

When running the code

```
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```

where `icon` is a custom `Surface`, meaning I filled parts of a surface, e.g. `icon.fill((255, 128, 0), (0, 0, 20, 10))`

The icon shows up as the backmost color which in my case is green, but when I save the icon to a file and load the image as the icon it works.

CODE:

```
Map_Surface = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
SKIN_DICT = {
    'Steve': (
        [(0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 20, 10)],
        [(0, 0, 0), (4, 4, 4, 4)],
        [(0, 0, 0), (12, 4, 4, 4)],
        [(255, 255, 255), (4, 4, 2, 2)],
        [(255, 255, 255), (12, 4, 2, 2)],
        [(128, 128, 128), (0, 10, 20, 7)],
        [(0, 0, 255), (0, 17, 20, 3)]
    )
}


def skin(name):
    for style in name:
        Map_Surface.fill(style[0], style[1])


skin(SKIN_DICT['Steve'])
```

When I put `Map_Surface` into `pygame.display.set_icon(Map_Surface)` The icon gets set to a solid green square.

```
pygame.display.set_icon(Map_Surface)
```

But when I put `Map_Surface` into `pygame.image.save(icon, 'icon.png')` and then do `pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('icon.png')`

```
pygame.image.save(Map_Surface, 'icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('icon.png'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to load your icon from a file. Simply call `convert_alpha()` on `Map_Surface`, as follows:

```
pygame.display.set_icon(Map_Surface.convert_alpha())
```

This sets the icon to a copy of `Map_Surface` with an alpha channel. Unfortunately I don't know why it fixes the problem. I originally tried to use `pygame.Surface.convert()`, however the icon remained as a solid green square.

See the documentation for `pygame.Surface.convert_alpha`:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha